# The Android invasion of jQuery

Tags: bug, status-completed, sponsored-tags

The [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag has the Android icon, any idea why?

[image: jquery]

Comment: What a way to find out Google bought jQuery.

Comment: "Needs more android"

Comment: Can we change the tag description to 'this isnt the android you are looking for?'

Comment: This isn't the droid you are looking for.

Comment: Better not get any of this in my vanilla-js... that's all I'm saying...

Comment: @Servy Or... jQuery bought Google! hahah

Comment: Have you considered using jquery to solve this problem?

Comment: @Liam Is Ólafur Waage [back at it again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492)?

Comment: @MattR MUHAHAHA

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is a bug. Some test data got out of its cage. I've fixed the issue and it should stop showing soon.

Comment: still showing up for me.

Comment: Doesn't seem like fixed for me.

Comment: Still showing up here. I guess at this point caching shouldn't really be an issue?

Comment: Yup, I'll look deeper into it today asap. Might be a _real bug_ with the way these things are handled. Will update as I manage to progress.

Comment: Still happening 17 hours later...

Comment: @Liam I am not seeing it though.. very odd

Comment: I still see this intermittently.

Comment: I only noticed it just now, dug out this post before I added a meta

Comment: Literally breaking... we should put SO on maintenance mode. :D

Comment: Should be _fixed_ now. It was intermittent for a while, but now it's consistently not showing. It was, of course, a caching issue. Cause it always is.

Comment: Sounds strange, so the cache evolved by itself and invented errors? :)

Comment: @davidkonrad I'm looking into what exactly went wrong with the caching. The thing disappeared only after a rebuild, so the cache failed to be updated _somewhere_. This is completely unfamiliar code to me however, so the going is slow.

Comment: It's fixed now :).

Comment: @HoriaComan http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Has anyone considered turning it off...waiting a bit...then turning it back on again?

Comment: I still see it right now.

Comment: @FooBar could you try an "empty cache + hard reload" in whatever browser you happen to be using?

Comment: I emptied my cache - all but my cookies&passwords, and attempted hard reload (ctrl F5) on Chromium - no avail.

Comment: @Liam How happy would you be if SO was unavailable for half a minute? What about 30 minutes? That is not an option. :-(

Comment: @wizzwizz4 [Let me introduce you to my friend irony, irony meet wizzwizz4](http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/61/612c2a41963c779a0477c6d5b91959a36ab2b351d9d117f19564d04fc63127c7.jpg)

Comment: @Liam Hello irony! :-D

Comment: @wizzwizz4 LOL!