# Tag sponsor accessibility

Tags: feature-request, sponsored-tags, accessibility

Leaving aside the fact that the current [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) tag on SO has an Android logo as a sponsor image (?), the images `alt` attribute is empty. It would be better if it said something like `Sponsored by Android` or equivalent.

Comment: Why? Usually, "feature requests" are accompanied by some reason why the requested feature is how it should be. I'm not very convinced screen readers need _more_ information there. Who sponsored the tag is irrelevant.

Comment: If the sponsor is irrelevant then the image is irrelevant? Or rather, if it doesn’t benefit a non-sighted user then it doesn’t benefit a sighted user either and should be removed completely.

Comment: I didn't say that. Who cares that _<company x>_ paid for the _<product y>_ logo? It's not relevant who bought the tag sponsorship.

Comment: Ah, right. I’ll edit my question.

Comment: _"Sponsored by Android"_? _"Android"_ is a product. A product doesn't have a PR department.

Comment: @Cerbrus: The whole point of sponsored tags is to increase brand exposure. There is nothing more relevant in a tag sponsorship than who's sponsoring the tag.

Comment: @BoltClock: If Microsoft decided to sponsor the jQuery tag, what brand would you want to see the tag "advertise"? What matters is what the ___tag___ is about. The only _useful_ alt attribute for a tag logo is _"<tag/product name> logo"_. Furthermore, the sponsor isn't even mentioned on the tag description / sponsored links block.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Why are you asking me this? Needless to say it's the responsibility of the company to ensure that they're sponsoring the right tags for the right reasons. If you're simply arguing that tag sponsorships shouldn't exist altogether, then this isn't the place to do so.

Comment: I'm just saying that there are better things to put in the image's `alt` than _who_ sponsored it. I'm not debating against tag sponsorship, not even close. I'm debating against making the tag about some company.

Comment: I disagree. SO has chosen to make the tag about a sponsor by allowing tags to be sponsored.

Comment: I'm not sure what else they'd put in the *alt* attribute to be honest? There's already text there saying *"jquery"* so that would be completely irrelevant to include in the attribute.

Comment: Money changes hands, a private company like SO has no interest in disclosing exactly whom gives them money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that it'd be better if the `alt` attribute were filled.

However, instead of the company that sponsored the tag, I'd rather see a more accurate description of the tag's logo:

```
alt="(Sponsored) logo for <tagName/productName>"
```

What *company* sponsored a tag should be available on the tag's information. Not *hidden* away somewhere in an `alt` attribute. We could even add a link to the sponsor in there.

From a user's perspective, *who* sponsored a tag isn't that relevant. I can imagine users getting tired of their screen readers saying *"Sponsored by Google"* after a couple of times.

TL;DR: It could do with an (non-empty) `alt` attribute, but sponsor information should be available elsewhere.

Comment: Wouldn't this make the `alt` attribute inconsistent with the actual content? I like your proposal about having the sponsor information available somewhere, to be clear. It's just that... it's the `alt` attribute of a logo. Shouldn't that attribute then say what the logo is from, and maybe why...?

Comment: @Justastudent: Yes, it should describe the image. So, for jQuery, it should say _"logo for jQuery"_ or _"jQuery logo"_, not _"logo from <Sponsor>"_

Comment: It's perfectly fine to leave the `alt` blank (or even add `role="presentation"`) if there's no information being conveyed that isn't already in text. Just saying *"hey, there's a logo here"* isn't really helpful to a screenreader. What the user needs to know is that it's a jquery tag and therefore they should leave the page ASAP. There's already text telling them that. What the screenreader **doesn't** know but seeing users can observe is the sponsorship so if anything should be added to the `alt` at all it should be that.

Comment: @ivarni: So, `alt="Tag sponsorship logo"`?

Comment: That wouldn't tell them who the sponsor is. I kinda agree with what you said when you said *"sponsor information should be available elsewhere"*. It's going to get noisy with a lot of sponsored tags on the page to the extent where I'd lean more towards just leaving it blank but I guess that's kind of something SO should discuss with the people who are paying for exposure in the first place. Most of the times people add text to the `alt` attribute it's not really needed. We've gotten flak for that before during UA testing by actual screenreader users.

Comment: Adding the sponsor’s name probably won’t be useful to a screenreader user, but then again neither is having (in this case) the Android logo against the jQuery tag for sighted users.

Comment: Yeah, that bit is a bug. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360358/957731

Comment: Ah, and now this starts to make a bit more sense. If a tag is only meant to be sponsored (or have an icon related to) something that matches its meaning then I can go with this answer.