# Tag icon spam (?) on mail-related tags

Tags: support, tags, advertising, sponsored-tags

A number of mail-related tags on Stack Overflow have an unconspicuous icon attached to them.

[image: Screen shot illustrating the problem]

My understanding is that this is a [sponsored tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean) but as the answer to the question I link to states, these should not be allowed on *"tags that represent generic concepts or are otherwise not strongly associated with the company purchasing them.*"

It looks like <del>all</del> *many of* the tags which contain the text "mail" in their name have this icon.

My real beef here is that I can't figure out what the icon is supposed to promote, but aesthetically, it would also be nice to simply get rid of it.

(The screen shot is from the "Related Tags" sidebar on the [`email-spam`](//stackoverflow.com/tags/email-spam/info) tag info page.)

Comment: Not all tags that contain the text _"mail"_ but a [fair few of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*mail*). Looks like SO have a discount sponsorship price for 10 tags, as my search returns 10 sponsored tags, but there's probably more

Comment: scratch that, searching [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) with _*mail*_ returns 16 sponsored tags

Comment: That doesn't seem kosher... That's just spam.

Comment: Also curious [tag:gmail-api] and [tag:gmail-imap] have the gmail icon

Comment: On the other hand, another competitor Mailchimp also has the SendGrid icon on [tag:mailchimp]

Comment: @Tanner Thanks for the update; edited question.

Comment: might be worth linking to this too: https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise/solutions/tag-sponsorship

Comment: Thanks for the link! It specifically says *"for copyright holders only"* (but can we trust a site which [doesn't display correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHmc7.png)?

Comment: @tripleee lol works on my machine, looks like that's what [Steve would have wanted](https://pi.tedcdn.com/r/pe.tedcdn.com/images/ted/0ef62e4df27b4ba7294de889fdbc33e476a08ec9_254x191.jpg?) on your machine

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This was done in error and will be corrected as quickly as possible. Thanks for bringing it to our attention. I'll provide an update when resolved.

Update #1: We've removed the 18x16 logos on those tags. It will take a while to propagate through the systems.

Answer (score 12):

> My real beef here is that I can't figure out what the icon is supposed to promote

They are from the company called Send Grid. Send Grid has [contacted SE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising) and is sponsoring that tag.

[image: Screen shot of sponsor banner]

You are not able to see that on the tag page, because you're a high rep user who has the privilege to see reduced ads.

Comment: Their web site seems to have a different icon which actually looks rather recognizable. How am I supposed to make the connection to them? Are they actually satisfied with the quality of the logo they ended up with?  And still, how does that sit with the policy to disallow icons on tags which are not "theirs", like [tag:email-spam], [tag:html-email] and, gosh, [tag:gmail]?

Comment: @tripleee similar to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359198/nativescript-sponsoring-ionic

Comment: marketing is bizzare

Comment: How can be [tag:gmail] tag sponsored by other company, but not Google?

Comment: @VadimKotov check the answer in my link

Comment: Again, the meta question I link to in my question *seems to* be saying this should not be allowed, regardless of the fact that we can be sure the *advertisers* like to be able to hijack a competitor's tag. Whose side are we on again?

Comment: I think it's like a bidding system, perhaps Send Grid paid more money than Google to get their logo on it. Not sure though, once a SE employee adds an answer I'll delete this.

Comment: Please keep it; I think this is informative and relevant (though some of the value is in the comments which are of course prone to be deleted anyhow).

Comment: According to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359287/4826457 by SO Ads team member, _Regarding the 18x16 tag logo on the actual tag, an advertiser can only purchase that type of tag logo sponsorship if they hold the trademark to that specific tag name_. This seems to have changed now

Comment: The site for [Tag Sponsorships](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/advertise/solutions/tag-sponsorship) also states "_Logo on tag: For copyright holders only, 18x16 static image, Transparent background recommended_". It can still be possible that this is just a bug, since this was the case in other similar question about [meta-tag:sponsored-tags]

Comment: @devpuh I couldn't figure out which "other similar question" you mean, could you provide a link please?

Comment: @tripleee [The Android invasion of jQuery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360358/8097737) was clearly a bug, [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187) says "_Stack Exchange no longer allows branding like this to be purchased for tags that represent generic concepts or are otherwise not strongly associated with the company purchasing them_" and i guess tags like [tag:imap] are generic concepts.

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought you were saying there was a problem with the image or the linkage to the correct image ... but yeah, it's possible of course. Should I perhaps post a separate meta question about that ...?